# Can't identify which section is locked that is prevent IIS config change

Tags: powershell, iis, iis-8

When running the command below it tells me its locked somewhere but I don't know where:

```
PS C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv> Set-WebConfigurationProperty -PSPath 'MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST/MYSite' -Filter "system.
applicationHost/sites/site[@name='MYSite']" -name "logfile" -value @{
>>  directory = "C:/inetpub/MYSite/logs"
>>  period="MaxSize"
>>  truncateSize="52428800"
>>  localTimeRollover="true"
>> }
>>
Set-WebConfigurationProperty : This configuration section cannot be used at this path. This happens when the section
is locked at a parent level. Locking is either by default (overrideModeDefault="Deny"), or set explicitly by a location tag with overrideMode="Deny" or the legacy allowOverride="false".
At line:1 char:1
+ Set-WebConfigurationProperty -PSPath 'MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST/MYSite' -Filter  ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Set-WebConfigurationProperty], FileLoadException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.IO.FileLoadException,Microsoft.IIs.PowerShell.Provider.SetConfigurationPropertyCommand
```

I confirmed that httplogging and system.applicationHost/log is unlocked at the server level. What else could be locked that is preventing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PSPath was wrong, should have just been "-PSPath 'MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST". That error message was really stupid and unhelpful.

This works:

```
Set-WebConfigurationProperty -PSPath 'MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST' -Filter "system.
applicationHost/sites/site[@name='MYSite']" -name "logfile" -value @{
 directory = "C:/inetpub/MYSite/logs"
 period="MaxSize"
 truncateSize="52428800"
 localTimeRollover="true"
}
```